# How to Disable telnet on Cisco switch totaly?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I have disabled telnet on Cisco 2960G switch by putting:

```
line vty 04
transport input ssh
```

but now when I try telnet to the switch I get message saying,password required but not set 
I am wondering if there is way to stop the switch totally from listing to the telnet port

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you actually configured

> line vty 04

Then you have something like:

```
line vty 0 3
 transport input telnet ssh
line vty 4
 transport input ssh
```

This is because you configured only the fifth VTY line (04=4).
The correct command is:

> line vty 0 4

or rather:

> line vty 0 15

since most (all?) modern Cisco switches have 16 vty lines and not 5.

You may also want to add access lists (ACLs) to allow only SSH traffic (and maybe SNMP and ICMP) destined to the switch.